# How do I display time in the modeline for the UTC timezone?

Tags: mode-line, time-date, mode-line-format

My system's time zone is set to the local time zone, but I want the time zone for Emacs to be set to UTC.

I've tried using various different functions, like `current-time-zone`, `current-time-string`, `current-time`, `format-time-string`, etc, and I've tried setting various variables like `display-time-format`, but no matter what I do, the time will only display for my local timezone. ChatGPT suggested that I try:

```
(setq display-time-format "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
(setq display-time-world-list '(("UTC" "0.0.0.0")))
(display-time-mode 1)
```

That didn't work, presumably because it only changes the time for the buffer resulting when `world-clock` is called. I did see time displayed for UTC when calling `world-clock`, but this didn't cause Emacs to display UTC time in the modeline. I asked ChatGPT again, and it suggested:

```
(format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" (current-time-string 'universal))
```

But this didn't work either, since the minibuffer displayed "Invalid time specification".

Any suggestions? I can't think of anything to try, and I don't know how to use any time offsets to adjust the display time.

Comment: This question is more about the OS than about Emacs. As the answer points out, in Unix-like OSes (Linux and MacOS probably), setting the `TZ` environment variable for the program is enough. I don't know if that works on Windows. On Unix-like systems, you can set the timezone for any program by invoking the program like this at the shell prompt: `TZ=UTC progname`. Try e.g. `TZ=UTC date` and of course `TZ=UTC emacs`.

Comment: BTW, this is a general mechanism: *any* env variable can be set that way for the invoked program. E.g. a common debugging technique is to have an env variable control verbose logging of the internals of an application, so that if you start it with `DEBUG_VERBOSE=1 myapp` you get all that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to change the timezone:

```lisp
(setenv "TZ" "UTC0")
```

See [Time Zone Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Zone-Rules.html) in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual.

Comment: Does this work on Windows?

Comment: exactly as you said, the reference says "If TZ is not in the environment, Emacs uses system wall clock time, which is a platform-dependent default time zone."

Comment: OK, thanks - [it also says further down](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Zone-Rules.html) that `All systems support the string
‘"UTC0"’ meaning Universal Time` so that is definitive.

Comment: While this does answer my question, that Elisp statement changes the displayed date and time for all my files in dired as well. As a result, two different dates are displayed for the same file in Emacs versus my GUI file manager, although the underlying information about when the files were created or modified is presumably kept consistent.

Is there a way to only change the displayed time for the modeline to UTC, and nothing else? If not, maybe I'll get used to the changes displayed everywhere else.

Comment: So it seems that you want to display a kind of `world-clock` in modeline, but I couldn't find a package that looks like it. Since the `time.el` that defines `display-time` uses Emacs-wide common date functions, I think it would require quite a bit of surgery to override `display-time` itself.